# How to make two diffrent Activities to use the same layout Android

Tags: android, layout, popupmenu

Below code works fine, but it opens a new layout and shows the toast message. but i wanted it to show toast  & *popup menus* on the current layout. I'm working on popup menu project, i want to show popup menu on same layout. Thanks in Advance.

**MainMactivity.java**

```
package com.example.twoact;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent openpopactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(openpopactivity);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**MainActivity2.java**

```
package com.example.twoact;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainActivity2 extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ya am in",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.twoact.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="142dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use a dialog and display the pop in the same activity. You can have a custom dialog

Comment: in manifestfile make the theme for MainActivity2 as dialog <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

Comment: pls read the docs on Activities and other ui elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use Popup menu and Popup window. in this you can use your custom layout so you can get your view as window in same activity.

Popup window will be good option because it is since API LEVEL 1

please refer this [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and [example 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html),[example 2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

And Popup Menu is since API LEVEL 11. so you have to manage for lower version

[docs for Popup Menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) and [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)

popup window